# Can RavenDB be interfaced outside of .Net?

Tags: ravendb

Is there a common data interface for [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/)? For example, how could Java, Python, or even PHP interact with RavenDB?

Comment: [HTTP API](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/csharp/http-api) can be used. PHP's cURL can be helpful in making API calls. Here's an example from [CodeWrecks](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2012/02/13/first-touch-of-ravendb-http-api/) and [RavenDB cURL examples](http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.0/csharp/http-api/http-api-single)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In RavenDB 3.0 they added a Java client as well. I haven't tried it myself, but you can read about it here:

http://ayende.com/blog/168354/what-is-new-in-ravendb-3-0-jvm-client-api

In that blog post Ayende also mentions:

> RavenDB has always been accessible from other platforms. We have users using RavenDB from Python and Node.JS, we also have users using Ruby & PHP, although there isn’t a publicly available resource for that.
>
> **With RavenDB 3.0, we release an official Java Client API for RavenDB**. Using it is pretty simple if you are familiar with the RavenDB API or the Hibernate API.

So to answer your question: No, there isn't a "common data interface" for everything, but most things are certainly doable.

Answer (score 0):

Almost every ravendb command is available through HTTP via REST.

For version 2.5 it is documented http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/2.5/csharp/http-api/http-api-single. For version 3 they ommitted that documentation (or it is not available yet), but it is still there.

The client (.net or java) is *'just'* a wrapper around those HTTP REST calls that does things like caching, serializing, failover, etc..., to make it much easier to work with RavenDB in your application.

Comment: HTTP REST calls for v3.0 are described here: http://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/3.0/http/client-api/commands/what-are-commands